# Image is shown as black and red colors only in ARKit

Tags: swift3, arkit, scnnode, ios11.2, scnmaterial

We are trying to create a SCNNode with a SCNMaterial which has an image (.png extension) in ARSCNView with the ARKit framework.
The problem is that image rendering has a problem that image is shown as black and red colors only, **it doesn't render image correctly.**
The problem exists only in iOS 11.2 version. There is no problem in iOS 11.0, 11.1 and 11.3 beta versions.


Our code is below;

```
let materialMain_Front_Back = SCNMaterial()
let fromBackImage = createImage(color:mainNode_Color)
materialMain_Front_Back.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "nodeBackground")

let materialMain_Other = SCNMaterial()
materialMain_Other.diffuse.contents = createImage(color:mainNode_Color)

let boxGeometryMain = SCNBox(width: CGFloat(mainNode_Width), height: CGFloat(mainNode_Height), length: 0, chamferRadius: 0.0)
boxGeometryMain.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
boxGeometryMain.materials = [materialMain_Front_Back, materialMain_Other, materialMain_Front_Back, materialMain_Other, materialMain_Other, materialMain_Other]

let nodeMain = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeometryMain)
nodeMain.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -1)

//... other codes

annotationNode.addChildNode(nodeMain)
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it just using .jpg images. Yes just using jpg image instead of png.
I also reported this to Apple as a bug. They answered as that is a problem in 11.2 only with grayscale images with transparency. They fixed it in 11.3.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem only occured on device, and continues to happen on iOS 11.4.

The solution for me wasn't the image type.  In my case I already had JPG textures, however the color space was greyscale.

Xcode showed this as:

[image: Greyscale Setting]

Changing it to RGB fixed the problem.  After changing it, Xcode shows this:

[image: RGB Setting]

Oh, and to change from greyscale to RGB using Photoshop, it's as simple as opening the image, and selecting: Image->Mode->RGB Color, as shown here:

[image]